# Vivante video memory size?

Tags: linux, software, graphics

I'm using an NXP i.MX 8MP, with Vivante GC7000UL and GC520L GPUs. Using the Etnaviv open source drivers.

For the life of me, I can't figure out how much video memory is made available to the GPUs, nor where to change it. If it's in the device tree, it's not in the GPU nodes.

Where can I find, and change, the amount of video memory allocated by the Etnaviv driver?

Comment: After investigation, [this bug seems relevant](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/mesa/mesa/-/issues/7153) - I am currently migrating to a newer kernel to make sure.

Comment: Because of short deadlines, I was forced to abandon investigating this, as moving from NXP Linux kernel to mainline proved to be too work intensive.

Comment: All those SoC vendors that are too cheap to mainline the kernel support for their hardware can go out of business as far as I'm concerned. They don't deserve our money. They are wasting everyone's time, and they definitely don't care for your - the customer's - time either.